# SQL Count on multiple joins with dynamic WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

My issue is that I have a Select statement that has a where clause that is generated on the fly.  It is joined across 5 tables.

I basically need a Count of each DISTINCT instance of a USER ID in table 1 that falls into the scope of the WHERE.  This has to be able to be executed in one statement as well. So, Esentially, I can't do a global GROUP BY because of the other 4 tables data I need returned.

If I could get a column that had the count that was duplicated where the primary key column is that would be perfect.  Right now this is what I'm looking at as my query:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    TBL1 1  
        INNER JOIN TBL2 2 On 2.FK = 1.FK
        INNER JOIN TBL3 3 On 3.PK = 2.PK INNER JOIN TBL4 4 On 4.PK = 3.PK 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL5 5 ON 4.PK = 5.PK 
WHERE   1.Date_Time_In BETWEEN '2010-11-15 12:00:00' AND '2010-11-30 12:00:00'
ORDER BY 
        4.Column
        , 3.Column
        , 3.Column2
        , 1.Date_Time_In DESC
```

So instead of selecting all columns, I will be filtering it down to about 5 or 6 but with that I need something like a Total column that is the Distinct count of TBL1's Primary Key that applies the WHERE clause that has a possibility of growing and shrinking in size.

I almost wish there was a way to apply the same WHERE clause to a subselect because I realize that would work but don't know of a way other than creating a variable and just placing it in both places which I can't do either.

Comment: Is FK your primary key? If so then why can't you group? Also keep in mind that you can group by more than 1 key

Comment: Grouping forces me to restrict data, If I could group I would but that means I only get one row based on that group by and I need multiple results where I can group by one column and persist that value through the multiple results count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or higher, you could use one of the [AGGREGATE OVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) functions.

```
SELECT  *
        , COUNT(UserID) OVER(PARTITION BY UserID) AS 'Total'
FROM    TBL1 1  
        INNER JOIN TBL2 2 On 2.FK = 1.FK
        INNER JOIN TBL3 3 On 3.PK = 2.PK INNER JOIN TBL4 4 On 4.PK = 3.PK 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL5 5 ON 4.PK = 5.PK 
WHERE   1.Date_Time_In BETWEEN '2010-11-15 12:00:00' AND '2010-11-30 12:00:00'
ORDER BY 
        4.Column, 3.Column, 3.Column2, 1.Date_Time_In DESC
```

Comment: You sir, are awesome.  I like finding things like this that I have never used/seen before.

Comment: Thx, appreciate the vote of confidence but if you want awesome, take a look at the postings of Quassnoi. http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a55159

Answer (score 0):

something like adding:

```
inner join (select pk, count(distinct user_id) from tbl1 WHERE Date_Time_In BETWEEN '2010-11-15 12:00:00' AND '2010-11-30 12:00:00') as tbl1too on 1.PK = tbl1too.PK
```

Comment: This would technically work however, my issue here is that when the WHERE changes on the outer statement how to I apply that to the subquery using straing SQL. Programmatically, the WHERE clause gets appended to the end based on other selections by the user